# Calculating a distances using eastings and northings UK (ordnance survey)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have downloaded the ordnance survey which contains the postcode eastings and northings of all UK postcodes and I would like to perform a mySQL query which calculates and shows the results of a given distance.

Firstly I need to match up all records in properties to the postcode table to show each properties easting and northing joined into the results.

I then need to calculate the distance between the given postcode and each property record and display only the ones which fall within the given distance.

I have found lots of examples for using long/lat but I cannot seem to find any good examples for using the ordance survey easting and northing system. According to the ordenance survey guide I should be getting an answer in metres for using the full 6 digits.

I am also getting this error:

errorErrormessage: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(((`mjm`.`pc`.`Eastings` - 436421) ^ 2) + ((`mjm`.`pc`.`Northings` - 291786) ^ 2))'

When trying to test the query:

```
$query = "
            SELECT * , SQRT( (pc.Eastings - {$e1})^2 + (pc.Northings - {$n1})^2) AS distance
            FROM properties p, postcodes pc
            WHERE concat( p.POSTCODE1, p.POSTCODE2 )= pc.Postcode HAVING distance <= 10
            LIMIT 0 , 30
        ";
```

Can someone help me understand what I need to do to make this work please?

Comment: The integer out of range error comes from squaring large integers and the result is larger than the largest integer. If you cast them to floating point numbers before you square them, this should not happen.

Comment: Would probably also be easier if you converted to lat/long before storing in your database; if you have a WGS84 lat/long then it's also a lot easier to display using GoogleMaps

Comment: What projection is this data in? I should hope it's in one appropriate for performing calculations in the UK since it's UK data, but it's worth double checking.

Comment: @MarkBaker distance calculations are actually harder in Lat/Long than in meters. Eastings and northings have already been converted to meters. The length of one degree of longitude depends on the latitude.

Comment: @flup - if you do the simplistic pythagorus calculation, yes.... but there's plenty of example libraries that you can use for a Haversine or a Vincenty great circle calculation between lat/long

Comment: @jpmc26 - If it's data from Ordnance Survey's CodePoint Open as OP says, then it will convert directly to OSGB36

Comment: @MarkBaker so you are suggesting to first move away from meters to latlon, and then use a library to recalculate the meters for each comparison?

Comment: Can you show min and max values for the northings and easting?

Comment: @flup - I'm suggesting that pythagorus calculations are for a planar geometry, so less accurate than something like Vincenty which uses a spheroid formula

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26201/discussion-between-flup-and-mark-baker)

Comment: @flup - and lat/long values are more useful for other purposes, such as plotting on a map

Comment: @jpmc26 - this is for UK.

Comment: @MarkBaker How would I go about converting them to long/lat? I dont require 100% precision but I just need to get this working one way or the other.

Comment: The simplistic version is casting to float for your existing calculation method.... there's a couple of pages on the web that describe the conversion to Lat/Long, but don't have the links to hand at the moment. I wrote my own classes to handle it, using my Geodetic library as the guts for handling the OSGB36->WGS84 conversion

Comment: Ouch! ^2 is not squaring but xor operator!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

^ is the XOR operator, not the square. Can you try this?

```
SQRT( POW(pc.Eastings - {$e1}, 2) + 
      POW(pc.Northings - {$n1}, 2)) as distance
```

Comment: errorErrormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS FLOAT)^2 + ((pc.Northings - 291786) AS FLOAT)^2 ) AS distance FR' at line 1

Comment: I have changed it to a different cast. Unsure why MySQL won't cast to float or what was wrong with my syntax. Apologies. Am still curious about the min and max values for the northing and easting columns.

Comment: It wont allow me to cast as a float.

Comment: $query = "
    SELECT * , ROUND(
         SQRT(
           ({$e1} - CAST(pc.Eastings AS DECIMAL(10,5)))^2
          + 
           ({$n1} - CAST(pc.Northings AS DECIMAL(10,5)))^2
          )

      / 1609, 5 ) AS distance
    FROM properties p, postcodes pc
    WHERE concat( p.POSTCODE1, p.POSTCODE2 )= pc.Postcode HAVING distance <= 10
    LIMIT 0 , 30
   ";

Comment: Take another look at the answer please, cause the ^2 is incorrect. You need pow

Comment: Cannot post as floats. Although this is now not bringing up the correct values. For instance the distance between CV100AB and CV116PE is showing as 0.45207 miles the actual distance is 2.924 miles http://www.freemaptools.com/distance-between-uk-postcodes.htm - cant understand where I am going wrong!

Comment: To square a number in MySQL you need POW(x,2) not x^2. I have edited the answer I provided.

Comment: errorErrormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SQRT(POW(pc.Eastings - 436779, 2) + POW(pc.Northings - 292308, 2)) AS distance ' at line 1

Comment: It is MySQL, yes? I have tested it over here and the expression is syntactically correct.

Comment: Yes.  $query = "
    SQRT(POW(pc.Eastings - {$e1}, 2) + 
    POW(pc.Northings - {$n1}, 2)) AS distance
    FROM properties p, postcodes pc
    WHERE concat( p.POSTCODE1, p.POSTCODE2 ) = pc.Postcode HAVING distance <= 10
    LIMIT 0 , 30
   ";

Returns above error.

Comment: Aah! Add SELECT *, at the start you removed a bit more than just the expression!

Comment: Excellent. Thats bringing up the correct results now. Thanks a lot!